# How to highlight different part of human anatomy when tapping on

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have searched enough, got one or two ways but failed to get an exact solution to my problem. I have an image of a body like this:

[image]

Now when tapping on different body parts, those bodyparts will be highlighted like below image:

[image]

This is a back body portion image for reference.

Now I have small images like:

[image]

To highlight the body parts. Can anyone please suggest me a way how I can achieve this. Just guide me with a way that will be enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fairly easy, let's say the full human body is 400x800, and you got like 5 body parts, then create 5x 400x800 images with each body parts in the exact location, stack each on top of each other, the invisible layer will match and display the whole body normally.

To highlight, simply switch the image in the corresponding `imageView`. To handle user touch, you should have a tap gesture to figure the location, then change the correct image layer.